# Why can not use gcloud-node in nodejs project

Tags: node.js, gcloud-node

I just start learning  how to use gcloud in nodejs project.
And I have already done the following step:

> npm install gcloud --save

But when I use gcloud in the file named *writeLog* like this:

> var gcloud = require('gcloud')({
>   projectId: 'testID'
>   });

There is a Typo note in the picture

[Typo note click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqbE.png)

node version : 5.6.0
gcloud version : 0.34.0
I use gcloud module to write log with a function named *writeLogs*, and export it. In another file named *index.js*, I require that function like this:

> var writeLogs = require('./writeLog');

then use this function.

After I run the project, it shows that
[problem click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTv4r.png)

I really don't know how to solve this problem. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you post more details? This seems to be not enough to judge what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my infomation. This is my first time to ask questions on this platform. Can you understand my question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure that you can name your variables however you want, but if it makes you feel any better, try naming the variable as 'gCloud' instead of 'gcloud'. Doing so, will make that typo error disappear.

Also, please update your gcloud package, node and npm to the latest versions and try. Please update your node version to >6 and npm version to >3.10.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It may be due to the computer environment and the node version.